# sync mobile device with a local server

Tags: sync, android, git, unison

Hello I have a two way synch scenario:

- multiple [archos android client devices](http://www.archos.com/products/imt/archos_5it/index.html?country=us&lang=en) (we plan to have up to 100 of them) that need to update small files (little txt logs) to a central server
- central server (could be either win or linux) that needs to distribute new content (some big files like photos or video) to all android clients
- both the server and all the devices are under wifi
- at the end of the day any android client will be connected via USB to their docks for further synchronization.

I have to design and implement the synchronization system for that scenario.

I thought about using [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [UNISON](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) in some sort of automated way and investigated a few hours about them. The communication needs to be two way and when the server distribute its content to all the devices the communication doesn't have to hang up.

- do you have any hint/pros/cons/real scenario about GIT for this purpose?
- Could the decentralized nature of Git help in some way? In other words could an updated device become a master for other clients in a sort of multi-master mesh networked solution?
- do you have any other protocol/technology to suggest me?

Please note that since an internet connection will not be available, a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not restricted/related necessarily to Android: I'm using Git to sync my home directory, my documents and many other stuff. Works great. Sometimes a bit 'too' powerful but I have some shortcut scripts for the most common tasks (like automatically pull, add new files, commit with some dummy message, push to some server -- all with just one single command). And I like having the full history. Whereby, if I don't want to keep some stuff of it, Git gives you the full power to just safe what you want of it.

The decentralized nature of Git is very helpful for me. I still have a server, mostly as a backup and to have some source where I can get my data when I have no other of my systems at hand. But I often also sync between my machines directly. All that is no problem via Git, you can just use it in whatever way you like.